# Variable Issues & Event Listener Issues: jQuery Enqueued Scripts in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have browsed several Q&A regarding difficulties with enqueuing scripts (including jQuery) into Wordpress, and most seem to cover the trouble that the scripts are not being found at all.

I am pretty sure I cracked that nut ok, my scripts appear to be found and loading correctly, but they are not behaving as traditionally expected.

Here is a truncated snippet of the code I placed in my functions.php file in a child theme I created:

```
<?php
function adding_scripts() { 
    wp_register_script('custom_styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_register_script('custom_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jQuery_scripts.js.php', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_scripts');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_styles');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adding_scripts' );
?>
```

This has successfully enqueued my custom CSS & to a degree my custom jQuery... but the jQuery is not working as expected. The coding is rudimentary, on par with my abilities, but ought to work.

There has to be some specific Wordpress noConflict 'something' I am missing

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            var variable1 = $(".element1").width();

            $(".element3").css({"width":variable1+"px"});
            $(".element4").click(alert(variable1));
});
```

The variable is not being created, that is the first problem.

The 'click' event I originally created to do a test to see what the variable was and found something curious. When the page loads, the click even fires without a click on `.element4`.

The return is `null` in that alert.

So the questions are: Why aren't the variable being created as they would normally  and  Why is the click even listener triggered without a click event on `.element4`?

Comment: What is header `Content-Type` of your file `jQuery_scripts.js.php` ?

Comment: @Jevuska - I don't have a header of any kind.  I am inferring that could be the source of my problems?

Comment: I just attempted to add this 'header' to no avail:
`<?php
/*Outputting jQuery*/
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
?>`

Comment: No, I just curious if you have php code inside jQuery_scripts.js.php, I test your code and its woking fine. For click even listener, you should use on('click' ...

Comment: Could you show the html code for `.element1`, `.element3`, `.element4`?

Comment: Ok - Bizarre warning.  The variable is now apparently being created, but the 'click' event is till being triggered without a 'click'.  And I don't know if this has any relevance, but I want to manipulate elements rendered from a plugin

Answer (score 0):

Well, as luck would have it, for an unknown reason(cache?) after about 8-10 hours after I enqueued the scripts the variables were being finally created. My alert test did return the element's width.

However, as stated in the comment, my `click();` was still being spontaneously triggered with no click.

As a test I changed to `.on("click",function(){});` and this seems to be working fine. I suppose that the jQuery library installed in Wordpress is not completely, totally the same as if linking to the remotely hosted one at jQuery or Google.

No matter, there is no further issue at this time, and while I did only half answer my own question, since I don't know the root causes of the issues in the first place, I guess half is close enough.